# Does the admin view has to have the public features of the app as well?

Tags: user-interface, admin, multiple-users

I am designing a website for tech events, which needs to have both an `admin display` and a `public / user display`. Admins of course can `manage events, users` etc. Users can `save events, register, share events`. E.g in the `public / user navigation` I have `tickets, reminders,` etc.

Now I can´t decide if all the `users features` has to be present in the `admin display` as well, or only the `admin / managing features`? What is `best practice` and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our university system, the admin can take over the role of any student.
This is to identify problems and / or help users not used to the system.
Also, when a new feature is added to the system, it helps a lot in terms of debugging and testing.

I think the biggest plus for this practise is to take the role of a user and see why a certain feature might not work correct, or where the said user has problems working with the system. 
This, of course, requires the users to trust the admins.